# Bootstrap carousel not loading images properly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get the bootstrap carousel to work, but when I load the page it just shows all 3 images at full size.

I've tried all the solutions I could find with no luck. I put the bootstrap script in the right spot. I included jQuery because apparently that's necessary (??). I marked one of the images as active.

The header/imports:

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        // Load this when the DOM is ready
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#carousel').carousel();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

The carousel:

```html
    <h1 class="text-center">Slideshow</h1>
    <div class="carousel" id="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active"><img src="img/food-1.jpg" alt="Food 1"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="img/food-2.jpg" alt="Food 2"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="img/food-3.jpg" alt="Food 3"></div>
        </div>
        <a href="#carousel" data-slide="prev" class="left-carousel-control">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#carousel" data-slide="next" class="right-carousel-control">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you want to use js to start carousel, the script need to be below your carousel HTML. Or you need to run that function inside jQuery document.ready. Did you try to put class for image because I saw in bootstrap example there is class. Maybe you have other css override bootstrap css image.

Comment: @DarknessZX I added the document.ready and I also tried to put the script after the html, and still nothing. What do you mean when you say "class for image"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using HTML code of Bootstap-3 and JS file of Bootstrap-4.

i.e, Incompatibility issue.

Here is the simple code for Bootstrap-4 slider.
[Bootstrap-4 Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/)

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080/?water" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080/?nature" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1920x1080/?food" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

If you want to use Bootstrap-3 version please refer,
[Bootstrap 3 Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#carousel)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap-4 provide simple carousel slider, you may try this simple example..

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```